# "The update failed to install" 10.14.3

Tags: macos, upgrade

My iMac is on 10.14.2. Every day I come to the office there is a popup on a black background

> The update was not installed successfully.
>
> You can try updating again in System Preferences after restarting.
>
> [ RESTART ]

There is no other option. When I click it restarts and is busy for 15 minutes.

Every day.

This upgrade is like Groundhog Day with Bill Murray. How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

First run Disk Utility & check the drive, then try running the Combo Updater instead of the downloaded delta.

Google can always easily find these, but the one for 10.14.3 is here -
[Apple Support; Download macOS Mojave 10.14.3 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1992)

Comment: Thank you. Tried this just now and same result. "Good morning. Off to see the groundhog?"